# Open several pictures and display them in a tiled fashion

Tags: image-viewer

I am looking for a program that:

- can open at once up to 4 (more is better) images into one screen, e.g. in a tiled fashion. All opened image must be entirely visible.

E.g. (with 4 images):

[image]

If possible:

- free
- works with Linux or Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.
- has an option to reload or even better auto-refresh the image is modified (actually pretty important, but I'll already be glad to be able to open and view 4 images at once).

I am aware of those [image viewers for Windows that auto-refreshes the image when it is modified](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6999/903) but as far as I know none of them can open 4 images and display them nicely so that I can see everything.

Comment: Workaround on Windows: Open the 4 images in separate instances, start the Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+ESC), hold down Ctrl and highlight the 4 windows with the images, then right click and choose Tile Vertically/Horizontally.

Comment: @Timmy Good idea!

Answer (score 2):

## [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

While not a dedicated image viewer, Emacs is a highly extensible text editor. You can split it into several windows, horizontally or vertically using the shortcuts `C-x 2`, and `C-x 3`.

It is cross platform, so it runs on both Windows and Linux. But it only natively support images on Linux. For the Windows installation, you'll need additional [GnuWin32 packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) to be able to view images. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650041/emacs-under-windows-and-png-files) for reference. Making images entirely visible can be done using the image+ package (available on [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/), with the shortcut `C-c M-m` (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674716/1836949)).

- Emacs is free
- It works on both Windows and Linux
- It can open multiple files in different buffers as tiled windows
- You can reload individual buffers using the command `M-x revert-buffer`, or you could  activate [`auto-revert-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoRevertMode) using `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`to update the images automatically when changes are detected

You can also find excellent community support on [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/)